# Knowing with PHP if the browser can play audio file with html5 audio tag

Tags: php, html, audio, browser, cross-browser

My question might be weird, but I don't know how to phrase it…

Actually, I would like to know whether or not the user's browser support mp3, ogg and wav files (I want the information for each).
I know, I could just make the distinction between firefox and safari/chrome for a start, but there are several browsers I wouldn't take into consideraton.

How could I proceed ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to reliably detect HTML5 audio (and subsequently codec support) is to do so client-side.  The only capability available to you with PHP (or anything server-side) is to do user-agent sniffing, which is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: Okay, thank you.
I'll do it client-side then.

How can I do it with JS (I'm already using jQuery if it makes it simpler).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr will do the deal in the end. http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5
Thank you !