# PHP: Check if file is displayable by browser

Tags: php, mime-types

I want to check if a certain file is playable by the browser.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
$playable = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg' ... 'video/mp4' ...];
if (isset($playable[mime_content_type($file)])) {
  // file is playable
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe a list of MIME-types which are playable by modern browsers?

Comment: At the very least, you could switch the conditional to use `in_array` rather than `isset`. As for your primary question, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678400/knowing-with-php-if-the-browser-can-play-audio-file-with-html5-audio-tag

Answer (score 0):

You could just serve up the content in the appropriate element based on the first half of the mime type. You can then use the `onerror` event handler to detect errors.

See [How does one use the onerror attribute of an img element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124866/)